# An infinite product involving triplets of consecutive prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, infinite-product

> Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime, $n\ge 1$. I was wondering if the following product converges
> $$P=\prod _{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_{k+1}}{\sqrt{p_k p_{k+2}}}$$

I have computed some numeric examples and the result  $1.224$ keeps the same $3$ decimals when $k$ goes from $10000$ on, which makes me think it converges, but I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

Any idea?

Thank you for your attention

**Edit**

The result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234978/existence-of-limit-ratio-of-consecutive-prime-numbers-elementary-proof) that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}=1$$
and the comment made by  Donald Splutterwit that the general term of the product can be written as
$$\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}}$$
let me conclude that the product converges to $$P=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: This product from $k=1$ to $n$ is equal to $\sqrt{\frac{p_2}{p_1}}\sqrt{\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n+2}}}$, right?

Comment: Telescope ... Converges to $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: you have proof that $\frac{p_{n}}{p_{n+1}}$ converges to $1$?

Comment: @NN2 Yeah, I think you are right ... that result is stated here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds ... maybe you could answer this for Raffaele & keep it out of the unanswered list ?